# How to convert the Timestamp in millis to Date with TimeStamp in Rest ful service?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am trying to do to convert the Date in millis to Date in timestamp by using Jersey Converters. but I am not able to convert. Pleae help me .

Entity class:

```
       @JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
             @Column(name="TSTAMP")
            private Timestamp timeStamp;
            **JsonDateSerializer:**
       @Component

            public

 class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Timestamp>{
        private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS");
        @Override
        public void serialize(Timestamp t, JsonGenerator gen,
                SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(t);

            gen.writeString(formattedDate);

        }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to convert date to timestamp

//use your formatted date here

```
 Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

Comment: I am getting the List from the DB as I expected but when I add the list Response in build() can changes the Timestamp in Millis

Comment: That is not . List<TagCollarData> ActivityDTOList = collarService.findMostRecentActivity(tagId, maxResults);                                     ActivityDTOList containes correct format but RestUtil.getOkResponse(dogActivityDTOList) -- now format is changing

Comment: didn't get u what do u mean by add the list Response in build() can changes the Timestamp in Millis